# Problem on a argument theorem complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, complex-integration

The problem states, if $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are root of polynomial
$ f(z) =z^3-z-1 $ then value of integral,

$ \frac{1}{2\pi\iota}\int_C{\bigl(z^9 \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\bigr)} dz
$

where c is curve containing all zeros of $f(z)$

What i know about this problem: if we know zeros of $f(z)$ then we can solve it using argument theorem which states this integral =
$\alpha^9 + \beta ^9 + \gamma^9$, since $f(z)$ doesn't have any pole.
but finding pole of this function is not easy. How to approach such questions.

**EDIT:** I did tried some manipulation but no luck.
$
\alpha$ is zero of $f(z)$ then $\alpha^3-\alpha-1=0 $ or
$\alpha^3=\alpha+1 $

similarly $\beta^3=\beta+1 $
and $\gamma^3=\gamma+1 $

so $\alpha^9 + \beta ^9 + \gamma^9$= $ (\alpha+1)^3+(\beta+1)^3+(\gamma+1)^3$ and then proceeding but no luck

**EDIT-2:**Continuing the above way,$\alpha^9 + \beta ^9 + \gamma^9$=$\alpha^3+1+3\alpha^2+3\alpha + \beta^3+1+3\beta^2+3\beta + \gamma^3+1+3\gamma^2+3\gamma$ =

$( \alpha +1) +1 +3\alpha^2+3\alpha +( \beta+1) +1 +3\beta^2+3\beta + ( \gamma+1) +1 +3\gamma^2+3\gamma
$ $\tag{1}\label{eq1}$
Now using the fact that sum of zeros of polynomial is coefficient second highest power. so $\alpha + \beta +\gamma = 0$ and sum of product of roots $\alpha\beta +\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma = -1$

(source for this information:https://www.myqbook.com/MathConcept/597/The-sum-and-product-of-the-roots-of-a-cubic-equation)

squaring both sides, $\alpha^2 +\beta^2 +\gamma^2 +2\alpha\beta +2\alpha\gamma +2\gamma\beta=0$ =

$\alpha^2 +\beta^2 +\gamma^2 =-2(\alpha\beta +\alpha\gamma +\gamma\beta)=2$

putting these values in equation 1 $4(\alpha +\beta+\gamma + 6 +3(\alpha^2+\beta^2 +\gamma^2) =6+3*2=12 $

Obviously solution given in comment by @conrad is much more elegant.

Comment: move the integral to infinity (large $|z|=R$) after reducing the rational function $\frac{3z^{11}-z^9}{z^3-z-1}=P(z)+\frac{Q(z)}{z^3-z-1}, \deg Q \le 2$ and then the result will clearly be the degree $2$ coefficient of $Q$ as $dz=izd\theta$, the integral of $P$ is zero by cauchy etc

Comment: @Conrad. Very nice. Saves a lot of calculation.

Comment: @Conrad thank you for your approach. also have a look at solution in my assignment , i couldn't understand it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15iuBb_hyWs3ja--8HMXVtRg0Xl-f-tLH/view?usp=sharing